# How to view UIView in IB without any device bezel or full screen safe areas?

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, interface-builder

Super simple IB question.

In a xib, if you add a view it will be the size of the chosen "View as: XYZ" device (by default an iPhone 11 currently), and will display with the device bezel, and have the safe area of that device as if the view was full screen.

If the view I'm designing is intended to be something like a custom control etc which is *not* full screen, then it makes no sense to have the device bezel and safe area.

[image]

To be able to change the view metrics etc, you need to:

1. Change the "Size" under "Simulated Metrics" to "Freeform"
2. Change "Top Bar" to none
3. Change "Bottom Bar" to none
4. Resize the view to a reasonable intended size

However, the view *still* is using the Safe Area of the full screen of the selected device:

[image]

### **How do you get rid of those safe areas?**

If I'm designing a custom view like a button, I want the safe area margins to be 0 all the way around so this actually looks like it will at runtime. The only way I've found is to select a device that has zero-sized safe areas (iPhone 8, iPad, for example).

[image]

In this last screenshot, I finally have a custom-sized view displaying with no device bezel, and zero-sized safe areas, but it's only by a strange way of getting there. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It isn't exactly clear what you are doing, but you can turn off safe area relative margins and safe area layout guides under the size inspector.  Note that this is different to hiding the bezel, which is simply achieved by setting the size to freeform (and which is purely a cosmetic effect.  It doesn't change how the view would layout at runtime).  Even if you do have safe area margins you can constrain a subview  to the superview rather than the margins.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is do layout in an arbitrary-sized view. Turning off the bezel and setting the size to freeform etc is easy enough to figure out. It seems I still would want to use *a* safe area to do layout within (because what if this view does end up near a safe area), so turning it off seems wrong, but the only other choice is the chosen device's safe area which makes layout really odd.

Comment: Only the root view of your view controller has to worry about the safe area and it isn't arbitrarily sized. If you are using your nib file to define a view that will be a sub view it doesn't have to worry about the safe area; the constraints you apply to that sub view when you add it to the root view can be relative to the safe area or not as required.